# Im watching the tutorials on unity. Error CS1002 and Error CS1519 pops up. does anyone know how to fix error?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, error-code

I copied what the script says in video but it gives me errors.

The video is called- "Unity 5- Roll a Ball Game - 3 of 8: Moving the Camera - Unity Official Tutorial"
Timeframe "4:32" is where you will see the full script in video

Script (image)-

line 9 is where all three errors are taken place

line 9-

Private Vector3 offset3;

errors-

Error   CS1002  ; expected

Error   CS1519  Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Error   CS1519  Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

screenshot-
[script in visual studios and errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyEsR.png)

Comment: private should be lowercase for starters. that might already help/solve your issues

Answer (score 2):

Here I give a screenshot.

[image]

**Note:** You have to change your code. There is not take **Private** you have to use **private**.
 I'll give my line of code below. It was working.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Camera_Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    private Vector3 offset;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174389/should-we-answer-or-comment-on-a-typo-question